# How to present status of a long running business process workflow in Winforms

Tags: winforms, user-experience

I have a long running business workflow process. I need to show the user what state it currently is in and what is it waiting for it to be complete. Somewhat like a visual representations of the workflow in progress.
Looked into progress bar, but it is not applicable here, since the process may sometime take 1 or 2 days if it got stuck in between while waiting for a manual input like an approval from the manager.
Is there a simple way someone has implemented this using nice visual representation? I do not want to use 3rd party tools like Telerik or ComponentArt. I have Ingragistics though but it does not have anything that could help us.

A typical business workflow will go through many stages. We can take an example of USPS tracking...where a particular mail goes through various stages or states...
Created.
Scanned or Origination.
Arrived at USPS, CA.
In Transit.
Arrived in IAD Airport.
Arrived scanned at USPS, Chantilly,
Out for Delivery.
Signed and Delivered.

I want to show these various stages of a particular workflow using a visual representation...colors, etc. If there are any UX widgets in Winforms that I can use would be great. Or, I can make one myself using existing Winforms or any third party widgets.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  Once you narrow your question with more specifics, you might have better luck on [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).  Be sure to read their on-topic guidelines before posting a question there.

Comment: I did add an example to make things more specific and offering more clarity.